# Leaflet R Popup with sprintf

Tags: r, leaflet

I've created a map with leafletR and I'd like the popup in `addCircles` to include 2 variables from my data set, but I'd like them each on a new line.

The code I've tried with `sprintf` is this, which works except it all shows on a single line. How can I split this across 2 lines?

```
popup= sprintf("Store: %s \n TY Sales: £%0.0f", Stores$Store, Stores$X2016)
```

Comment: try something like: popup <- paste0("<strong>Store: %s: </strong>", 
                      Stores$Store, 
                     "<br><strong>TY Sales: £%0.0f: </strong>", 
                      Stores$X2016)

Comment: thanks, this works. Stores$X2016 was a currency though, and I've lost the formatting. How can I include custom formatting in that?

Comment: do as you would do it in a html doc.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this, can you help me with that?

Comment: try this ...TY Sales: &pound

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML formatting along with sprintf to insert italics, line breaks, and links.

```
 library(htmltools)

  labels <- mapply(function(x, y, z, a) {
    HTML(sprintf("%s<br><em>%s</em><br>%s<br><a href=%s>link</a>", htmlEscape(x), htmlEscape(y), htmlEscape(z), htmlEscape(a)))},
    data$var1, data$var2, data$var3, data$var4, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```